# Entity Framework checking for Insert or Update with same method

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have seen the current code base that the entity framework methods with repository pattern and UOW pattern have this

"IsNew" method  It works great most of the time for Inserts and Updates but the problem I ran into is that it is checking for if the ID = 0  , then to insert.  The problem is that the database table cannot be changed and it has **a non auto incrementing ID**

Thus here is the **method called**

```
public virtual void InsertOrUpdate(TEntity entity, bool startTrackProperties)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity.IsNew())
            {
                Entities.Add(entity);
            }

            AttachForUpdate(entity, startTrackProperties);
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            var msg = string.Empty;

            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    msg += Environment.NewLine +
                           string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);

            var fail = new Exception(msg, dbEx);
            throw fail;
        }
    }
```

I call it like this

```
public void CreateOrUpdateReportGroup(ReportGroup reportGroup)
    {

        var entity = _envyUnitOfWork.ReportGroups.GetById(reportGroup.Id);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            entity = new ReportGroup();
        }

        _envyUnitOfWork.ReportGroups.InsertOrUpdate(entity, true);
        Mapper.Map(reportGroup, entity);
        _envyUnitOfWork.Commit();
```

}

Problem is that I am looking up the greatest ID and adding 1 to it, but with the current code-base,  this IsNew() is a problem.

Thoughts on how I can more easily and cleanly do an insert with a non-incremented ID column?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is.  You say that `IsNew()` works great most of the time.  What happens when it doesn't work great?  Do get an error?  What are you expecting to happen that isn't happening?

Comment: Even when i override IsNew to not be zero based to indicate it is a new record to insert,  the database thinks that null is coming on over.,.  EF must be thinking to still send null on over for the ID and thus crashing on a table with primary key that does NOT seed

Comment: What does `IsNew` do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
 Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```